# What datatype in Oracle would map to a Java long?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g

What type in Oracle (10 Express Edition) would be the "same" as a Java long?

Comment: Long is a 64bit signed value - just check the documentation on Oracle numeric types to find a value that is the same, or bigger, and signed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java `long` primitive ranges from -2<sup>63</sup> to 2<sup>63</sup> - 1.

In Oracle `NUMBER(19)` covers the same range with the same precision.